# User wise display data in the Listview

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, listview

First of all. I have 3 tabs,

as

```
<ul class='tabs1'>
            <li><a href='#tab1'>All News</a></li>

            <li><a href='#tab2'>For NGO</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab3'>From NGO</a></li>
        </ul>
```

By default *#tab1* data is displayed. The other two tabs has a logic to display as User wise.

**If SuperAdmin uploads the data then the data should be displayed in FOR NGO and if**

**Admin & Users uploads the data then the data should be displayed in FROM NGO.**

I have given roles to them as

*Super Admin  --> 0
 Admin  --> 1
*Users  --> 2.*

For Displaying for all users I have the code like this:-

```
private void BindNews()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Please see the reference [here](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1014240793635)

Also see the listview code for `ALL NEWS`

```
  <div class="Newsdivalign">
                <asp:ListView ID="lstNews" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lstNews_PagePropertiesChanging">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="Newsdiv">
                            <p class="Newspara"><a id="a1" runat="server" href='<%# string.Format("#{0}", Eval("Id")) %>' class="modal-popup"><%# Eval("title") %></a></p>
                            <p class="NewsDate">
                                News Posted:
                                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm:ss tt}", Eval("dateforPost")) %>'></asp:Literal>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label"><%# Eval("ngo_name") %></span></p>
                            <p class="NewsDate1"><a href='<%# Eval("title") %>'>Click here</a> to know more </p>

                        </div>


                        <div id='<%# Eval("Id") %>' class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-container">
                                <div class="popup-content">
                                    <div class="popup-close js-popup-close modal-close">X</div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p class="popup-para"><%# Eval("title") %></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="padding: 7px;">
                                        <p class="NewsDate">
                                            News Posted:                                   
                                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm:ss tt}", Eval("dateforPost")) %>'></asp:Literal>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="SStorypara">
                                            <%# Eval("description") %>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
                <div class="pagination clearfix">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="dpNews" runat="server" PagedControlID="lstNews" PageSize="10">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </div>

                <%--<div id="testMsg" class="popup">
                    <div class="popup-container">
                        <div class="popup-content">
                            <div class="popup-close js-popup-close modal-close">X</div>
                            <div>
                                <p class="popup-para">Recognition statement</p>
                            </div>
                            <div style="padding: 7px;">
                                <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST</p>
                                <p class="SStorypara">
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>--%>



                <%--<div id="testMsg" class="popup">
                    <div class="popup-container">
                        <div class="popup-content">
                            <div class="popup-close js-popup-close modal-close">X</div>
                            <div>
                                <p class="popup-para">Recognition statement</p>
                            </div>
                            <div style="padding: 7px;">
                                <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST</p>
                                <p class="SStorypara">
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                                    the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                                    of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                                    also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                                    recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                    Ipsum.
                                </p>
                                <p class="SStorypara">
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                                    the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                                    of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                                    also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                                    recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                    Ipsum.
                                </p>
                                <p class="SStorypara">
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                                    the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                                    of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                                    also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                                    recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                    Ipsum.
                                </p>
                                <p class="SStorypara">
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                                    the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                                    of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                                    also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                                    recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                    Ipsum.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>--%>

                <%--  <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="#testMsg" class="modal-popup">Recognition statement</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span>&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span> </p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                </div>--%>

                <%--<div class="pagination clearfix">
                    <a href="#">First</a>
                    &nbsp;<a href="#">«</a>

                    <a href="#">1</a>
                    <strong>2</strong>
                    <a href="#">3</a>

                    <a href="#">»</a>
                    &nbsp;<a href="#">Last</a>
                </div>--%>
            </div>
```

Please help

Comment: I don't seem to see a question or error description?

Comment: @BerndLinde: My `All News` data are displaying correctly, I want the query to display the data for `from NGO` and `For NGO`

Comment: Update your question with that information and explain how you differentiate between the roles in your data. Because from your SQL select, I do not see a role column or anything related to how you explained you want to split the information

Comment: @BerndLinde: I guess I have added in question the roles. I will update the HTML part if you want. Also with the listview which displays all the data

Comment: There is still no indication as to on what you want to split your data from what is returned by your SQL select. From the columns returned by the SQL, which one of those will determine if this was posted by a SuperAdmin, Admin or User? Determining that, will allow you to filter your listview accordingly

Comment: @BerndLinde: See, I have 3 tabs,I am getting the data for the `ALL NEWS` from the query posted in the question. Now I have given the roles to admin and Users as 1 & 2 respectively. Now when any users/admins logs in and post the data, that should also go in `FROM NGO` and if SuperAdmin posts the data it should go in `FOR NGO`. Do you want any data related to `sql tables` ? I have User table related to the roles and usernames also